# delete by query | elasticsearc 2.4.0

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ES-2.4.0 for my application and I have a use case of deleting multiple documents in single query. I am trying to use ***delete by query plugin***, but facing the following exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to find action org.elasticsearch.action.deletebyquery.DeleteByQueryAction@7c1ed3a2] to execute
        at org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClient.doExecute(NodeClient.java:56)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:359)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:86)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:56)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.deletebyquery.DeleteByQueryRequestBuilder.execute(DeleteByQueryRequestBuilder.java:172)
```

Below is my implementation

```
if (StringUtils.isEmpty(clusterNodes)) {
                // embedded mode
                Settings.Builder settings = Settings.settingsBuilder().put("path.home", "./");
        if(embeddedTcpPort!=null){
          settings.put("transport.tcp.port", embeddedTcpPort);
        }
        if(Boolean.valueOf(httpEnable)){
            settings.put("http.enabled", true);
            if(embeddedHttpPort!=null){
            settings.put("http.port", embeddedHttpPort);
            }
        }
        Node node = nodeBuilder()
                .local(true)
                .settings(settings.put("plugin.types","org.elasticsearch.plugin.deletebyquery.DeleteByQueryPlugin").build()) //added delete plugin
                .node();
        node.start();
        this.client = node.client();
    } else {
        // cluster mode
        String[] clients = StringUtils.split(clusterNodes, ",");
        Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name",
                clusterName).build();

                TransportClient tClient = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings).addPlugin(DeleteByQueryPlugin.class).build();
        for (String val : clients) {
            String[] pair = val.split(":");
            if (pair.length != 2) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        Messages.ES_CLIENT_NODE_ERROR);
            } else {
                                try {
                                    tClient.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(
                                        InetAddress.getByName(pair[0]), Integer.parseInt(pair[1])));
                                } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
                                    throw new IllegalStateException("Could not set up ElasticSearch connection", ex);
                                }
            }
        }

        this.client = tClient;
    }
```

My maven dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>delete-by-query</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Please help me out here. How should I proceed and where I am making mistake? Is ***delete by query plugin*** is available in ES2.4.0? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to add plugin type to your settings:

```
Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
                         .put("plugin.types", DeleteByQueryPlugin.class.getName());
```

Did you install plugin?

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.4/plugins-delete-by-query.html

Comment: I have not installed the plugin but I have added it for both embedded mode and cluster mode.

Comment: I have added it in my code(You can see in my code). But not installed it. Do i need to installed it although I am adding it in my code?

Comment: You have to install plugin on each node in cluster. _The plugin must be installed on every node in the cluster, and each node must be restarted after installation._ from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.4/plugins-delete-by-query.html