# elasticsearch 2.4.0 | delete multiple documents using query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a use case of deleting multiple documents using query and I have achieved that implementing the below code for ES 1.7.0

```
DeleteByQueryRequestBuilder deleteQuery =
client.prepareDeleteByQuery("my_index_name");
deleteQuery.setQuery(QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery(Constants.INDEXER_INSTANCE_NAME, sourceTitle))
.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery(Constants.ENTITY_INDEXED_TYPE,Constants.ENTITY_INTERNAL)))
.setTypes(getTypeEntity());
deleteQuery.execute().actionGet();
```

But delete-by-query is removed from core(not available in 2.4.0). How I can achieve the same functionality in 2.4.0?

Comment: I believe there is a delete-by-query plugin that you can install to get this functionality in Elasticsearch 2.X

How to [install](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.0/plugins-delete-by-query.html). The reasoning is [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/core-delete-by-query-is-a-plugin)

Comment: The answer in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42746672/delete-by-query-elasticsearc-2-4-0?rq=1) question may be of help to you.

Comment: any other way without using the plugin?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, sorry.